# Proc Freq into a dataset in SAS Studio

Tags: sas

I have a data (colour) that looks something like

Id haircolour
1 black
2 brown
3 grey 
.....

And using `proc freq` I got a table that looked like

Haircolour Frequency
Black 10
Brown 20
Grey 30

Is there any way for me to save this table as a new sas file with `haircolour` and `frequency` as the variables?

Thanks
Tim

Answer (score 1):

There are two main ways to get data out of a proc. 
One way is to use the OUT option on the TABLES statement. 
Another is the ODS OUTPUT statement, however that depends on your table statement.

```
proc freq data=sashelp.class;
      table sex*age / out=want;
run;
```

The ODS approach is outlined here.
https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2017/01/09/ods-output-any-statistic.html